# is there any way of making this program more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the program to be more efficient, i was thinking to use a 'for loop' but i dont know how to implement it in my code and also the writing to file part is really long i want to make it shorter

```
    import random

    def character_attributes():
        initial_value = 10
        character1_strength = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))
        character1_skill = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))
        character2_strength = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))
        character2_skill = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))

        print("Character 1 now has a strength attribute of {0}".format(character1_strength))
        print("Character 1 now has a skill attribute of {0}".format(character1_skill))
        print("Character 2 now has a strength attribute of {0}".format(character2_strength))
        print("Character 2 now has a skill attribute of {0}".format (character2_skill))

        myfile = open('character_attribute_data.txt', 'w')
        myfile.writelines('Character 1 has a strength attribute of : ')
        myfile.writelines(str(character1_strength))
        myfile.writelines('\n')
        myfile.writelines('Character 1 has a skill attribute of: ')
        myfile.writelines(str(character1_skill))
        myfile.writelines('\n')
        myfile.writelines('Character 2 has a strength attribute of : ')
        myfile.writelines(str(character2_strength))
        myfile.writelines('\n')
        myfile.writelines('Character 2 has a strength attribute of : ')
        myfile.writelines(str(character2_skill))
        myfile.close()
```

Comment: I'd suggest making a class for your characters including member functions that return formatted strings for a printed output of the attributes (possibly by overloading `__repr__()`), and another method that dumps this string to file, which eventually uses the `with` statement for this task. But after all, this has neither to do with efficiency nor with Python 3.x.

Comment: sorry what I meant by efficiency is less lines of code

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can get much more efficient in the sense of higher speed. You are using python functions for all the string manipulations and you will hardly get any better in python.

But your code is not that efficient concerning development speed. Imagine you want to change 'Character' by 'Person' then you have to change 8 lines of code. The answer of unutbu for example gives you a hint for a much better solution and even this could be improved e.g by introducing a class for characters as pointed out by moooeeeep. Even if you now think this is pure cosmetics, it will on the long run helps you to improve performance as you will be able to make changes (e.g. an optimisation you found) in contrast to the current code which is not maintainable.

Another point  is, I can hardly belief that you really get into performance problems with this code. It does nothing than writing some few lines into a single file. Be very careful to not optimize things you don't need to (premature optimization). Only if you get into performance problems, then analyze the bottlenecks and try to improve the worst.

EDIT:
Sorry, i meant moooeeeep comment on the question:
This is a prototype extending the example from unutbu with a class holding the attributes information:

```
import random

class Character(object):
    '''
    This class holds all the information concerning a character, it's attributes, 
    the character number, ...
    '''
    def __init__(self, character_number, initial_value):
        '''
        Initialize a new character object with character_number and initial_value
        '''
        self.strength = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))
        self.skill = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))
        self.character_number = character_number

    def get_attributes_dict(self):
        '''
        return a dictionary with the attributes names and their values for this character
        '''
        return {'strength': self.strength,
                'skill': self.skill
                }


def writeout_character_attributes(characters_list):
    '''
    this function writes a complete list of character into a file
    '''
    #The 'with' statement is used here, because it automatically closes the 
    #file at the end of this block, so you cannot forget it 
    with open('character_attribute_data.txt', 'w') as myfile:
        #iterate over the character in the list
        for character in characters_list:
            #get all the attributes for the current character
            attributes = character.get_attributes_dict()
            #iterate over the attributes names and values, 
            #defined in the character class
            for attribute_name, val in attributes.items():
                msg = "Character {i} now has a {attribute_name} attribute of {val}".format(
                    i= character.character_number, attribute_name=attribute_name, val=val)
                print(msg)
                myfile.write(msg+'\n')


def get_list_of_characters(initial_value):
    list_of_characters = []
    # we want two characters with numbers 1 and 2
    for i in range(1, 3):
        #create a new character
        character = Character(i, initial_value)
        #add this character to the list of characters
        list_of_characters.append(character)
    return list_of_characters

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_of_characters =  get_list_of_characters(10)
    writeout_character_attributes(list_of_characters)
```

It's maybe not less lines of code, but it is much easier for example to add more attributes or add komplex logic to the Character class

Comment: Can you add a relevant link for moooeeeep and/or a brief prototype for the class you mentioned that might help the OP?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make the code more efficient, but it does make it shorter:

```
import random

def random_val(initial_value):
    return  initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))

def character_attributes():
    initial_value = 10
    with open('character_attribute_data.txt', 'w') as myfile:
        for i in range(1, 3):
            attributes = {
                'strength': random_val(initial_value)
                'skill': random_val(initial_value)}
            for key, val in attributes.items():
                msg = "Character {i} now has a {key} attribute of {val}".format(
                    i=i, key=key, val=val)
                print(msg)
                myfile.write(msg+'\n')
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand that piece of code quite good I'm only a beginner